# How do I call a second function within the same CFC in the APPLICATION scope?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfc

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1.

Let me start by stating that I may not be asking the right question. Since each function works independently and fails only when one function calls another, I am thinking that the problem is in how the function is called.

I am creating an application variable that contains a structure. The structure contains the reference to an object, orders.cfc.

```
if (not isDefined("APPLICATION.AppInfo") or not isStruct(APPLICATION.AppInfo)) {
    APPLICATION.AppInfo = structNew();
    APPLICATION.AppInfo.objOrders = createObject("component", "globaladmin.orders");
}
```

I am able to successfully access the methods in the orders.cfc like this:

```
OrderItemList = APPLICATION.AppInfo.objOrders.orderItemList(URL.Customer);
```

I have methods in the orders.cfc that call other methods in the order.cfc, kind of like this (faked for simplicity):

```
<cffunction name="orderItemList">
    <cfscript>
          LOCAL.RandomNumber = getRandomNumber();
          return LOCAL.RandomNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getRandomNumber">
    <cfscript>
        LOCAL.SomeNumber= randRange(0,10);
        return LOCAL.SomeNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

I get this error:

```
Entity has incorrect type for being called as a function. The symbol you provided getRandomNumber is not the name of a function.
```

I figured maybe I can't reference a function within the same CFC without creating an object first, so I do this:

```
<cffunction name="orderItemList">
    <cfscript>
          LOCAL.RandomNumber = APPLICATION.AppInfo.objOrders.getRandomNumber();
          return LOCAL.RandomNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Then, I'd get this error:

```
Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types, or the method getRandomNumber is overloaded with arguments types that ColdFusion can't decipher reliably. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, you may need to use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.
```

How should I call a second function within the same CFC?

Comment: Do your simplified examples toss out the error in your environment?  I only ask because if I copy and past your examples and run them locally I run into no errors.  Just wondering if perhaps some hidden details that might be the cause of the error.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of the CFc that is stored in Application scope actually has the 2nd method? I have been bitten by that where I make changes to an object stored in shared scope, but do not refresh that object after change has been made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I would try is var scoping your all your variables within your functions:

```
<cffunction name="orderItemList">
    <cfscript>
          var RandomNumber = getRandomNumber();
          return RandomNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getRandomNumber">
    <cfscript>
        var SomeNumber= randRange(0,10);
        return SomeNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, let me know and we can explore further.

*edit*
Okay, now that the local scope issue is resolved, try this:

```
<cffunction name="orderItemList">
    <cfscript>
          LOCAL.RandomNumber = THIS.getRandomNumber();
          return LOCAL.RandomNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getRandomNumber">
    <cfscript>
        LOCAL.SomeNumber= randRange(0,10);
        return LOCAL.SomeNumber;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Note the update, and the "THIS." prefix to the function call.

Comment: Jake, that was the answer. I slowly moved everything (relevant) to the THIS scope and slowly the errors went away. Thanks for being AWESOME!

Comment: Something else must be going on, you should not need to use THIS to call a function in the same CFC.

Comment: @ScottStroz - You're right, it shouldn't be necessary.  I suggested it because I still suspect a problem with scope conflicts; now, not with local variables, but instead with some global variable named getRandomNumber.  Adding the "this" scope on that reference works around that problem.